# Trying to make stack column bar chart with specific start and end time. Can use Jscript or php

Tags: php, javascript, charts, jqplot, fusioncharts

Thank you for taking the time to read my post this is taking me ages.

Basically I want to create a graph that displays 07:00 at the bottom to 20:00 at the top of the y axis. Then on the x axis I want the days of the month. Then the users clocking in/out activity in the graph as in clocked in duration and clocked out duration on that day. The main problem I am having is how to specify a start and end point for each of the stacked bars (each clock in/out activity) is any library I've tried (tried jqplot and FusionCharts)

If anyone could suggest a php/javascript library that would allow me to create a stacked column bar chart that lets me specify the start and end point of each entry in the stack that would be great. (sort of like the block plot in jqplot but with bars)

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [Visifire](http://www.visifire.com/). Visifire supports developing charts and gauges from JavaScript as well as Managed code. Please check out the following links:

http://www.visifire.com/silverlight_stacked_charts_gallery.php

http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Quick_Start/Silverlight/Working_with_JavaScript.htm

As you working with DateTime values for both AxisX and AxisY inside the chart, Visifire supports DateTime values in AxisX only but you can display DateTime values in AxisY also using CustomAxisLabels feature. For more info please check the link below.

http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Reference/Chart_Elements_Reference/CustomAxisLabels.htm